# Multiple to-many NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, ios, nspredicate

I have a model with a couple of to-many relationships.

System ->> Item ->> Code

I'm trying to write a predicate on a fetchRequest for System.

I only want to show Systems that have Items that have at least one Code.

I have tried a SUBQUERY but I just can't get it to work.

This is what I've tried...

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(items, $x, $x.codes.@count != 0) != 0)"];
```

I've tried other various permutations of this but they all throw similar errors.

Could someone let me know what the correct predicate format is?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add another `@count` for the SUBQUERY:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(items, $x, $x.codes.@count != 0).@count != 0"];
```

Comment: Hi Martin, I haven't actually tried it yet, sorry. I gave up and moved on to a different part of the app before I saw your answer. When I get back there I'll def update you though.